# How to dynamically query and visualize PostGIS data using GeoDjango and OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, openlayers, query, geodjango, web-gis

I am trying to implement dynamic query functionality in GeoDjango and OpenLayers. First, I filter the data and return it in GeoJSON format using Django serialize. Then, the return GeoJSON data visualize using OpenLayers 6. It works fine. But, When I try to filter data dynamically, it is not working. I don't understand the problem. How can I fix this?

```
// GeoDjango Model

    from django.contrib.gis.db import models

    class Boundary(models.Model):
        division = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        district = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        upazila = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        union = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.division

// views.py

    def boundary_data(request):
        """ bnd = Boundary.objects.filter(district="Khulna")""" // it is working fine
        name=request.GET.get("district")
        bnd = Boundary.objects.filter(district__iexact=name) // not working 
        boundary = serialize('geojson', bnd) 
        return HttpResponse(boundary, content_type='JSON') 

// urls.py 

    from django.urls import path
    from . import views 
    urlpatterns = [
        path('boundary-data/', views.boundary_data, name="boundary-data"),
        path('bgd/', views.MapView.as_view(), name="bgd"),
    ]

// query form

    <form method='GET' class="form-inline" action="">   
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="district" name="district" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

//OpenLayers code

    var style = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'gray',
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'white',
                width: 1,
              }),
              text: new ol.style.Text()
            });

  

    var map = new ol.Map({
              target: 'map',
              layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                new ol.layer.Vector({
                  source: new ol.source.Vector({
                      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                      url: "{% url 'boundary-data' %}"
                  }),
                  style: function (feature) {
                    style.getText().setText(feature.get('union'));
                    return style;
                  }
                })
              ],
              view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([89.5403, 22.8456]),
                zoom: 10
              })
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of `views.MapView.as_view()` section as well? And another thing is, I think you need to provide the action parameter in your form.

Comment: class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "bgd/index.html"

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between your filter form and Geojson data called by OpenLayers. You can choose from a couple of solutions. If you want to fetch data in your OL code block, you can create an event handler to catch district change from a dropdown (prepopulated by district names) and include selection in url like:

```
url: "{% url 'boundary-data' id=district_id %}"


urlpatterns = [
    path('boundary-data/<int:id>', views.boundary_data, name="boundary-data"),
    path('bgd/', views.MapView.as_view(), name="bgd"),
]

def boundary_data(request, id):
    bnd = Boundary.objects.all()
    if(id):
        bnd = bnd.filter(pk=id)
    boundary = serialize('geojson', bnd) 
    return HttpResponse(boundary, content_type='JSON')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I follow your guideline and try several-time but failed to create an event handler. I can't figure out how to create an event handler. Can you give me a full example mentioned in yourscomment?